# server block requests from local system

Tags: nginx, load-testing

Recently I'm trying to load test my Nginx server using siege. But when I'm trying to load test my server it working for a small concurrent user like 10 users but when I increased the concurrent users then my server block the requests from my local system for around 10-20 minutes. When my server blocking my requests and where I have to change the configuration for allowing requests for the same.

Comment: What you mean under blocking? You receive 403? Or couldn't connect?

Comment: I'm getting 0 hits on siege and also url starts not working from postman from local system

Comment: @AlexanderT And on the browser it says `This site can’t be reached server took too long to respond` from the local system but it opening on another system.

Comment: I have also WordPress and node js running on the same server on different ports, is both interfere with each other?